# How to do soft delete with mongodb using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm able to delete data from the view , but at the sametime its getting deleted from mongodb which shouldn't happen.

I tried mongoose-soft-delete plugin to perform soft delete, but it isn't working

//schema

```
var mongoose= require('mongoose');
let softDelete = require('mongoosejs-soft-delete');
var Schema=mongoose.Schema;
var newblogSchema=new Schema({
    user_id:Number,
    title:String,
    description:String,
    summary:String,
    hashtag:String

})
var newblogs=mongoose.model('NewBlog',newblogSchema);
newblogSchema.plugin(softDelete);
module.exports=newblogs;
```

//html template

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Summary</th>
        <th>HashTags</th>
    </tr>
   <tr *ngFor="let blog of blogs;">
        <td >{{blog.title}}</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <td [innerHtml]="blog.description| safeHtml">{{blog.description}}</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <td>{{blog.summary}}</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <td>{{blog.hashtag}}</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <td> <a routerLink="/blog"><button type="button" 
        (click)="editblog(blog._id,blog.title,blog.description,blog.summary,blog.hashtag)">
    Edit</button></a>
        <td><button type="button" (click)="deleteblog(blog._id)">Delete</button>   
   </tr>
  </table>
```

//ts file

```
deleteblog(blogid) {
    var result = confirm('Want to delete?');
    if (result === true) {
      this.blogservice.deleteblog(blogid).subscribe(response => {this.blogs = response; });

    }
```

//service

```
deleteblog(blogid):Observable<any>{
    return Observable.create(observer=>{
      this.http.post('http://localhost:4000/api/deleteblog', {_id: blogid}, {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'})}
      )
      .subscribe((response:Response)=>{
        observer.next(response);
        observer.complete();
      });
    });

   }
```

//api.js

```
router.post('/deleteblog',(req,res)=>{
    var body=req.body;
    newblog.findByIdAndRemove({_id:body._id},(error,newblog)=>{if(error){
        console.log(error);

    }
    else{
        return res.json({message:'deleted',data:newblog});
    }

});
});
```

Now the data is getting deleted from view as well as mongodb.

Expected result is to delete data only from the view and not from mongodb

Answer (score 2):

we can implement soft delete with plugin, middleware and $isDeleted document method

soft delete plugin code:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

export type TWithSoftDeleted = {
  isDeleted: boolean;
  deletedAt: Date | null;
}

type TDocument = TWithSoftDeleted & mongoose.Document;

const softDeletePlugin = (schema: mongoose.Schema) => {
  schema.add({
    isDeleted: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
    deletedAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: null,
    },
  });

  const typesFindQueryMiddleware = [
    'count',
    'find',
    'findOne',
    'findOneAndDelete',
    'findOneAndRemove',
    'findOneAndUpdate',
    'update',
    'updateOne',
    'updateMany',
  ];

  const setDocumentIsDeleted = async (doc: TDocument) => {
    doc.isDeleted = true;
    doc.deletedAt = new Date();
    doc.$isDeleted(true);
    await doc.save();
  };

  const excludeInFindQueriesIsDeleted = async function (
    this: mongoose.Query<TDocument>,
    next: mongoose.HookNextFunction
  ) {
    this.where({ isDeleted: false });
    next();
  };

  const excludeInDeletedInAggregateMiddleware = async function (
    this: mongoose.Aggregate<any>,
    next: mongoose.HookNextFunction
  ) {
    this.pipeline().unshift({ $match: { isDeleted: false } });
    next();
  };

  schema.pre('remove', async function (
    this: TDocument,
    next: mongoose.HookNextFunction
  ) {
    await setDocumentIsDeleted(this);
    next();
  });

  typesFindQueryMiddleware.forEach((type) => {
    schema.pre(type, excludeInFindQueriesIsDeleted);
  });

  schema.pre('aggregate', excludeInDeletedInAggregateMiddleware);
};

export {
  softDeletePlugin,
};
```

you can use as global for all schemas

```
mongoose.plugin(softDeletePlugin);
```

or for concrete schema

Answer (score 1):

For Soft delete, you should maintain an active flag column that should only contain values as 0 and 1.

This way, you could analyse whether a record is deleted or not.

While displaying, add another clause for displaying only the records that have flag value 1. And while deleting, just update that flag's value to 0.

This would do the job.

For Example, here user 2 is deleted. with activeFlag as 0.

```
ID      memberID    userStatus  groupCode  activeFlag
1       user1       1           4455           1
2       user2       1           4220           0
3       user3       2           4220           1
```

Comment: @Sethulakshmi You had a query? I see you deleted a comment.

Comment: yeah I had a query...I did as you said set an active flag to 1 and while clicking delete button, i updated the flag value to 0. After that how to view the records that have flag set to 0?

Comment: You mean the ones you soft deleted? It's simple. While making a normal `find()` or Select query, add a condition of `activeFlag:0` . It's simple and easy to use. Let me know if you still have a query.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/soft-delete-mongoose-plugin

A simple and friendly soft delete plugin for mongoose.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31476592)